# Google MDL - Side Drawer Menu - Not working when made as a separate component & used in another component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, material-design-lite

I have an Angular 2 app with a dashboard page that has a side-drawer menu, I made the side-drawer menu as a separate component and used in the dashboard template. I have added code and images for both non-working & working case below.

Both parent & child component have :

```
window["componentHandler"].upgradeAllRegistered();
```

in their respective 'ngOnInit' methods.

**NOT WORKING CASE :**

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<slide-panel></slide-panel>
```

**side-panel.component.html**

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
  <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
  <nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Add New User</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Import User Account</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">My Account</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Update Remote Firmware</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Logout</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image: Non working Screenshot]

**WORKING CASE :**

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <slide-panel></slide-panel>
</div>
```

**side-panel.component.html**

```
<span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
  <nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Add New User</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Import User Account</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">My Account</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Update Remote Firmware</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Logout</a>
  </nav>
```

**OUTPUT :**
[image]

I have marked the html element changes ( in blue ) in both the images. I know whats happening is not correct.

1. What is going wrong here ?
2. What is the proper way of doing this, to create reusable-MDL-styled-angular2 components to be used in other components ?

Thanks in advance.